# Specialize static template function of base class

Tags: templates, c++11, static, typedef, template-specialization

I'm trying to specialize a static template function from a base class, and figured this was a good use case for a typedef/using statement. I can't seem to get it to work, though. Is this illegal, or is my syntax wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    template <typename T>
    static T func () {
        std::cout << (T)3.145 << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
//  using derivedFunc = Base::func<int>; // This doesn't work
//  typedef Base::func<int> derivedFunc; // Nor this
    static constexpr auto derivedFunc = &Base::func<int>; // But this seems to work
};

int main() {
    Base::func<double>(); // Prints 3.145
    Derived::derivedFunc(); // Prints 3
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `using` or `typedef` expect a type to create a type alias, but you are passing a value, namely a pointer to a function. The last line which works does exactly that: The `auto` is deduced to a pointer which is assigned the pointer to the function. It becomes more explicit if you write it *without* `auto`:

```
static constexpr int(*derivedFunc)() = &Base::func<int>;
```

Or if you use this:

```
using derivedFuncType = decltype(&Base::func<int>);
static constexpr derivedFuncType derivedFunc = &Base::func<int>;
```

which in the first line shows how to get the required type from the function pointer and use the type alias to define the actual member variable from it.

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8187f0bda9433cc9)

In all cases, you now have a function pointer. The pointer itself is `static`, hence the pointer can be accessed with `Derived::derivedFunc` and it can be *called* with `Derived::derivedFunc()`.

Comment: Ah, I somehow thought C++ allowed alias declarations of template functions the same way as template classes. But obviously they are different things. Static pointer it is, then.